# Use Excel conditional formatting to format values ​below the average for the month

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016

I want to use the conditional formatting, only the values ​​that are below the average and specifying the month referring to the column, Ex: Jan = 273, Feb = 222, 291, etc ... how do I do it ??[image]

Comment: Can you please clarify your requirements? Are you trying to highlight cells if their SUM is less than the average by months? What is in cell G26, and is it even related to this? What does cell G27 have to do with it? Are you trying to only highlight cells in the matching month which are below average for that month? Would a heat map be a better approach here?
Can you explain or show a worked example (eg you highlight the cells manually and screenshot it as the expected result)

Comment: Yes, highlight only the average values ​​for the month searched

Comment: If I enter the month of January, I want his average and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Your conditional formatting formula will be a fairly simple AND() function, checking both G26>B27 and G27=B26, resulting in this:
`=AND(G27=B26,G26>B27)`, then setting your formatting appropriately.

Major contributing info from [This site](https://www.xelplus.com/conditional-format-index-match-result/) under the section halfway down, "Highlighting the lookup value in the data set"

Comment: It does not work, I tried to add the dollar sign but the formatting still does not apply

Comment: It does work, if everything is set up right. Provide a link to your file and someone will point out what you have wrong.

Comment: I already managed to solve the problem! Using the following formula: =E(B27<=$G$26;B$26=$G$27). My Excel is in Portuguese version. Some dollar signs had to be removed to define which rows and columns will be formatted according to the criteria